# What is difference between ‘give rise to’ and ‘cause’?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

‘give rise to’ means ‘to cause something’ in the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/give-rise-to). But I think ‘arise’ is more similar to ‘cause’ than ‘rise’ according to [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/arise-or-rise?q=Arise%2Bor%2Brise).
What is difference between ‘give rise to’ and ‘cause’? And why ‘rise’ not ‘arise’?

Comment: The idiomatic expression is “give rise” which has a transitive usage, unlike arise and rise.

Comment: We can also use ***occasion*** as a verb meaning ***to cause [to occur]*** - for example, [*His death occasioned her much grief.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/occasion) There's not much point in trying to pin down possible nuances of difference between ***give rise to, cause, occasion,*** etc. - just assume they *can* be synonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word ***rise***, in this context, is a noun meaning *beginning* or *origin*, whereas ***arise*** is a verb which means *to begin to occur or to exist*.

So ***give rise to*** means to cause the beginning of something, e.g. *The general's success gave rise to new problems.*

If you want to use *arise* instead you could write it as *The general's success made new problems arise.*